# JS: Help me understand why I cannot use this pre-defined function as callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I've been working through the very excellent [learnyounode](http://nodeschool.io/#workshoppers). My solution to one of the exercises looks like this:

```
var http = require('http'),
var url = process.argv[2];

http.get(url, function(response){
  response.on("data", function (data){
    console.log(data.toString())
  });
});
```

The above code works. However, I also tried this:

```
var http = require('http');
var url = process.argv[2];

http.get(url, function(response){
  response.on("data", readData(data));
});

function readData(data) {
  console.log(data.toString());
}
```

I get the error 'data not defined' (line 5). Why is this? Am I not calling the function in the same way that I'm calling the anonymous callback? As I understand it, response.on's second argument should be a function but it should make no difference whether that function is named or anonymous. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: You can, but, you're instead calling it and using its return (which is undefined) as the callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't pass the function as callback, you passed its return value.
using "readData(data)" will call the function and pass the value returned.
however to pass a callback you just need to write the function's name.

this is how you do it:

```
response.on("data", readData);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing now is actually calling `readData` instead of passing it as a `function`.

Try it like this:

```
var http = require('http');
var url = process.argv[2];

http.get(url, function(response){
  response.on("data", readData);
});

var readData = function(data) {
  console.log(data.toString());
}
```